# Outlook notifications

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email, notifications, outlook

Normally when I receive emails that goes directly to a folder the application does not notify of the new email unless I go to the folder and sincronize..

Is there any solution for this?
The notifications only appear to work on the inbox..

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Outlook Mail
- At the bottom of screen, press **...** and go to *settings*
- Click on first option, *Manage Accounts*
- Click on your desired account(if you have more than 1 email account)
- Click on " **Change mailbox sync settings** "
- Change *Download new e-mail* setting to "**as items arrive**"
- Click save and exit.

Comment: This answer does not apply- the question refers to sub folders within Inbox. Emails to these sub folders do not get push notifications.

Comment: the question doesn't quote that!